# Why are Analyzers dependencies missing in Visual Studio 2019 ASP.Net Core MVC Razor pages project?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I've created a new Visual Studio 2019 ASP.Net Core MVC Razor pages project. 
And I have the dreaded yellow triangle undere:

Dependencies -> Analyzers.

The dependencies all point to local files.

I have rebuilt the project, closed the solution, closed VS 2019.  Restarted VS 2019, reopened the solution.

What gives?
Why are these analyzers even in the project by default?
Such a waste of time.
Anyone know what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: I also unchecked "ReadOnly" on the folder I am creating the project in and deleted the project and recreated it. Still same problem.

Comment: What's your system environment? Have you tried creating other versions of the project? Will there be the same problem? Have you tried creating the same project on another computer to see if there is anything wrong?

Comment: Windows 10. Sometimes restarting everything works.